# nightmarjs очистить поле перед заполнением

Tags: node.js, nightmare.js

Приветствую всех вошедших

Толи лыжи не едут, то ли уже март.. Использую nightmarejs, захожу на сайт, далее надо заполнить значение в определенное поле, подождать, считать результат с другого поля

Но, всегда есть но.. проблема в том, что в поле уже есть значение (его кстати нет в GET параметрах страницы) а я когда пытаюсь вписать свое значение - дописываю свое, к тому, что уже есть в поле

```
nightmare
  .goto('https://mysite.ru/')
  .type('#sized_weight', '5')//тут беда, дописывает значение
  .click('#sized_volume')
  .wait('#bill-total')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#bill-total').innerText)
  .evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector('#bill-total').innerText;
  })
  .end()
  .then(function(result){
    res.send(result);
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    //console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```

Вопрос прост, подскажите, так такое пофиксить. Поле в которое дописываю значение там изначально прям в HTML коде есть value ( это не placeholder )

Comment: Плохо читаете API может быть? Пустое значение параметра `text` в `type()` приведет к очищению поля. А потом запустите еще раз, но уже с нужным значением. P.S. если двойное применение команд не возбраняется в данном скрипте. P.P.S. прямого очищения поля в API я не нашел

Comment: вариант! на ..ццатой странице гуголя вычитал вариант решения без дублирования команд 
нужно перед устанавливаемым значением вписать - .evaluate(function(){document.querySelector('#sized_weight').value='' }) ну или установить сразу нужное